# Getting last value from preg_match in php

Tags: php, preg-match

I have a string conting some url in it, How can I get the last url from the string

```
$myString = "::http://www.example.com/test/2015/06/27/mob/image_285245.jpg::http://www.example.com/test/2015/06/27/mob/image_288733.jpg::http://www.example.com/test/2015/06/27/285245";

        $pattern = "/http:\/\/(.*?)\/\d/";
        preg_match($pattern, $myString, $results);
        echo $results[1];  

//I want this:
//http://www.example.com/test/2015/06/27/285245
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this below code,

```
<?php 
    $myString = "::http://www.example.com/test/2015/06/27/mob/image_285245.jpg::http://www.example.com/test/2015/06/27/mob/image_288733.jpg::http://www.example.com/test/2015/06/27/285245";
    $results = explode("::", $myString);
    echo end($results);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
http://www.example.com/test/2015/06/27/285245
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$myString = "::http://www.example.com/test/2015/06/27/mob/image_285245.jpg::http://www.example.com/test/2015/06/27/mob/image_288733.jpg::http://www.example.com/test/2015/06/27/285245";

$results = explode("::", $myString);

echo array_pop($results);
```

Output

```
http://www.example.com/test/2015/06/27/285245
```